# Simple connected graph with equal sum and product

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, combinations

Find out how many simple connected graph is possible such that  sum of degree of vertices is equal to product of degree of vertices.

My Approach:
Assume that the graph has $n$ vertices . Denote $x_i$ for  degree of $i$ th vertex .

$\textbf{lemma 1} $ There exist atleast one vertex with degree $1$.

$\textbf{lemma 2}$ Sum of degrees of vertices is strictly less then $2n$

$\textbf{lemma 3}$ only tree is such possibility .
(But it's not true for all tree)

From lemma 3 we can say that we have to find out solution for $x_1+\cdots +x_n =x_1\cdots x_n =2n-2$.

I found for $n=7$ we can get a configuration like $(x_1,\cdots ,x_7)=(1,1,1,1,1,3,4)$ should work .
From here I assume if $r$ components has degree $1$ then $n-1-[\log_2 n]\le r\le n-2$.

If anyone need proof for my Lemmas then I should provide it .
From Here I need help

Comment: This question is part of an [ongoing contest](https://www.pravega.org/events/science_eve/Enumeration.html) and has been locked per the site's contest policy.